# Как установить windows на macbook aluminium late 2008?

Tags: windows, macos, macbook

Хочу установить windows 10 на macbook late 2008. Но BootCamp говорит такое

[image: bootcamp]

Драйвера он мне дал скачать, но устанавливать ничего не хочет. Сделал по другому, создал на ноутбуке с виндой установочную флешку, вставил в macbook и при загрузке с зажатым Alt видна флешка (по имени EFI), но выбрав ее macbook просто зависает. Подскажите пожалуйста как быть в данной ситуации.

Винчестер имеет такую разметку

[image: разметка винчестера]

Comment: Простите за оффтоп, но что вынуждает ставить Win 10 на Mac? Я к тому, что - ну это же нормальный мак? На нём же можно под iPhone приложения комфортно писать. А это - Win 10. Или Вы второй системой хотите Win поставить?

Comment: Посмотрите утилиты маковские для работы с разделами. Создайте на базе имеющегося самого крупного раздела подраздел для Win, и уже после этого спокойно ставьте систему на новый раздел. Может быть что-то вроде Partition Magick сможет помочь.

Comment: 1. Система конечно же нужна как вторая, от mac os я не отказываюсь ))   2. Пробывал отрезать кусок даже форматировал в NTFS, но при загрузке нифига не грузится, просто после выбора флешки комп зависает, ну а bootcamp все ровно говорит что, что то не так (на скрине)

Comment: Ставьте винду в виртуалке. И много проблем сразу решится. Главное оперативной памяти поставить побольше.

Comment: Ее как раз и не сильно много )) Ну вообще хотелось бы нативно поставить винду.

Comment: На сколько мне известно одновременно поставить мак и винду не возможно на один винт... конфликт форматов не даст этого сделать.

Comment: всё можно ставить, не даром есть bootcamp, тут может просто места на винте не хватает, сам когда имел две системы, но перешёл на Parallels

Comment: Конфликтов никаких нет,  mac os и windows ставиться на один винчестер, при том mac os имеет формат HFS+ а windows NTFS, на скриншоте выше он ругается что не может разбить на разделы, если я правильно понимаю, то диск должен быть как одиночный, то есть диск с резервными копиями надо было удалить, но вот winclone оказался самым удобным вариантом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все решилось таким путем:

1. Устанавливаем Winclone
2. Качаем образ windows под winclone, в моем случае это windows 8.1
3. Через дисковую утилиту создаем новый раздел в формате MS-DOS (FAT)
4. Разворачиваем наш образ windows на новый раздел с помощью winclone
5. Если winclone ругается и не хочет разворачивать образ, значит надо выключить SIP.
6. Заходим в Recovery (Cmd+R), открываем терминал, и пишем

   `csrutil disable`
7. Загружаемся в Mac OS и вновь пробуем развернуть наш образ
8. После всех операций можно (нужно) включить обратно SIP, так же заходим в Recovery, и в терминале прописываем

   `csrutil enable`